# Summarizing data by multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql-server

My boss is asking me to code a report that has the following components:

- A pie chart of employee count by state
- A pie chart of employee count by age bracket (10 year brackets)
- A pie chart of employee length of service (5 year brackets)
- A pie chart of employee Male/Female breakdown
- A pie chart of employee count by salary band (computer generates brackets).

There may be others.

I know I can do this by writting 5 different sql statements. However it seems like this would generate 5 table scans for one report.

I could switch gears and do one table scan and analyse each record on the front end and increment counters and probably accomplish this with one-pass.

Which way would the collective wisdom at stackoverflow go on this?

Is there a way to accomplish this with the CUBE or ROLL UP clauses in T-SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is properly indexed, those reports may not require any table scans at all.

Really, for a problem like this you should code up the reports the simple way, and then see whether the performance meets the business requirements. If not, *then* look at optimisation strategies.

Comment: I concede your second point. 

However I challenge you to come up with an index scheme that allows me to get stats on "Employee Age" in 10 year bands that would avoid a table scan.

Comment: @Aheho in order to summarize you need to scan, if you do male/female then the index is also worthless because of very low selectivity

Answer (score 2):

if you want 5 pie charts and need to summarize then you need 5 SQL statements since your WHERE clause is different for each

Comment: Not true. 
I could pull all the relevent records over to the front end, and then build the statistic in a foreach () loop.

Comment: I am talking about pure SQL, in your case you would have to group by all the different criteria and bring back how many rows?

Comment: Currently the largest report would have to summerized 30K-40K rows.

Comment: are you sure that 5 SQL statements would not be faster (assuming all the WHERE clauses are properly covered)? than pulling everything over the NET (this might take a while) and then looping over all these rows?

Comment: I'm not sure which is faster. I could do both and time it, but that would involve doing twice as much work. 

In addition, if my boss adds a new summarization category, the 2nd method wouldn't need any data access changes.

Answer (score 1):

You *may* have some performance gains by storing intermediate results in a table variable or temp table, then running more aggregation against it. Example with only two result sets:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, State, AgeBracket 
INTO #t
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY State, AgeBracket;

SELECT SUM(cnt) AS cnt, State FROM #t GROUP BY State;
SELECT SUM(cnt) AS cnt, AgeBracket FROM #t GROUP BY AgeBracket;
```

Comment: Hey Alex, nice to see you here :-)  Keep in mind that when doing (I know you know this already) a SELECT INTO against a large table you will get locking